# Ajax going to Error before return

Tags: jquery, ajax, wcf, wcf-rest

I am using ajax to call multiple function one of that function is too long and have several loops in that , when ajax call that function it goes to error of ajax before return from function , but at same time that function is in processing and return after some time.

```
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    type: "POST",
    url: url + methodName,
    timeout:900000,
    async: false,
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    beforeSend: function (xhr) { xhr.setRequestHeader("ClientSessionID", guid); },
    data: stringifyData,
    success: function (msgg) {
        successFunction(msgg);
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        errorFunction(xhr, status, error);
    }
});
```

This is my ajax calling , i even try to give timeout in ajax as well as wcf service side.still going to error function and giving 404 error (but ajax call hitting the service method) before returning from function at server side.

Any help will be highly thankful.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: provide the Response returned to the Error function

Comment: it is returning
in XHR:{"readyState":4,"responseText":"","status":404,"statusText":error},
status:"error",
error=""

but I want that data in Sucessfunction that return from server side function .

Comment: It is 404 because server is returning **Resource not find** status back to client,although it may be hitting to server..but after that it is going 404

Comment: Thanks for replying.
what could be the possible reason behind that.
because it returns to ajax error at same time pointer is not returned from server(it is processing at that function on server side).

Comment: No possible reason i can guess without seeing your code chunks..